# Add line of text to the list of figures

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft

For my report, I create a cover on illustrator with figures and I would like add line to the list of figures to add a note about it:

```
    \documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
 \usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{dummy figure}
\end{figure}
 
\listoffigures
   \addtocontents{lof}{{}{\emph{Hannibalszug 6}, Alfred Rethel, 1842}}~\hfill{couverture}
\end{document}
```

But when I want to add a second line, I have a problem :

```
\addtocontents{lof}{{}{\emph{Hannibalszug 6}, Alfred Rethel, 1842}}~\hfill{couverture}
   \addtocontents{lof}{{}{\emph{Hannibal crossing the Alps}, \emph{Comic History of Rome}, John Leech, 1850}}~\hfill{couverture}
```

What is the problem in my code? And a last question, how can I put lines at the top of the list?

Thanks a lot, and sorry for my rough English

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you were looking for?  Note: the last line doesn't fit inside \textwidth.

[image: lof]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
 \usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{dummy figure}
\end{figure}

\listoffigures
  \addtocontents{lof}{\hbox to \textwidth{{\emph{Hannibalszug 6}, Alfred Rethel, 1842}~\hfill{couverture}}}
  \addtocontents{lof}{\hbox to \textwidth{{\emph{Hannibal crossing the Alps}, \emph{Comic History of Rome}, John Leech, 1850}~\hfill{couverture}}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks a lot ! it's ok, but how can I put this line before the first figure in the list ?

Comment: The easiest way is to put the \addtocontents inside the figure in front of the caption.  It's first come, first served.